# Itext 7 SplitByOutlines - final document stays open and can't be closed

Tags: itext, itext7

I've written a custom splitter to split my PDF by the outlines/bookmarks.  It works but the problem is the last document remains open and is corrupted.  The document shows there are 71 outlines but the splitter returns back only 70 even though it created 71 documents.

Here is the custom splitter:

```
class CustomSplitter : PdfSplitter
{
    private int _order;
    private readonly string _destinationFolder;
    private readonly string _podName;
    private readonly IList<string> _splitFileNames;

    public CustomSplitter(PdfDocument pdfDocument, string destinationFolder, string podName, IList<string> splitFileNames) : base(pdfDocument)
    {
        _destinationFolder = destinationFolder;
        _order = 0;
        _podName = podName;
        _splitFileNames = splitFileNames;
    }

    protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
    {
        string splitFileName = _destinationFolder + "\\" + _podName + _order++ + ".pdf";
        _splitFileNames.Add(splitFileName);
        return new PdfWriter(splitFileName);
    }
}
```

I need to keep track of the names of the files so I can rename them.   I call my custom splitter with this code:

```
IList<string> splitFileNames = new List<string>();
PdfSplitter pdfSplitter = new CustomSplitter(pdfDoc, yearDir, fileName, splitFileNames);
IList<PdfDocument> splitDocs = pdfSplitter.SplitByOutlines(outlineNames);
```

This is the first time I am posting here.  I did search and found nothing that used SplitByOutlines.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, please attach the PDF to reproduce the problem

Comment: Hi, how do I do that?  I can't see a way to attach files.

Comment: Just use any file sharing service (OneDrive, Dropbox etc) and post the link to the file.